# Elastic search index mapping custom date format issue

Tags: date, elasticsearch

I have timestamps in some log files in this format: `12-Jun-2020 11:56:23.272` and I am trying parse these in elasticsearch using this mapping definition: `"time_stamp": {"type": "timestamp", "format": "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mM:ss.SSS" }`

I have tried various variations like `d-MMM-y H:m:s.S` 
but always get `"reason":"Invalid format: \"12-Jun-2020 11:56:23.272\" is malformed`

I have been using ES [manual](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) and [joda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) docs but find the joda specs leave a lot of room for interpretation.  In particular should it be dd or d for the days.  I found a tutorial [here](https://www.journaldev.com/17899/java-simpledateformat-java-date-format) which has more examples and spells out that for moths Mar needs MMM and March MMMM

In the mappings have tried "type" of both date and timestamp and that does not appear to make any difference.

Comment: Which version of Elastiscsearch are you using?

Comment: Elastiscsearch 6.8.6

Comment: I was able to index this date using the format `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mmn:ss.SSS`, and the `type` as `date`, there is no `timestamp` type. What `GET yourindex/_mapping` gives you? Update your question with the part about the `time_stamp` field.